# emberjs dynamic routing, serialize giving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Tags: routes, ember.js

Why is an error thrown inside the `serialize function` line `id = context.get('id');` 
Specifically why is it even attempting to run the serialize when I load the index route.

`full demo:` http://jsfiddle.net/mh8Xu/1/

```
   serialize: function(router, context) {
                    var rtnVal = {},
                        id = context.get('id');
                    if (context) {
                        rtnVal = {post_id: id};
                    }

                    return rtnVal;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in `{{action goToShowPost context="post" href="false"}}`.
I believed it was backward compatible, but seems it's not.
Now you have to directly pass the context, like this:

`{{action goToShowPost post href="false"}}`